# Need help importing Electron in Aurelia app

Tags: electron, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I'm using one of the skeleton-navigation, skeleton-typescript.

I'm trying to import Electron.remote so I can close the electron window from within the JS. This is what I have in config.js:

```
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "node_modules:*": "node_modules/*"
  },
  map: {
    "electron": "node_modules:electron/index.js",
  }
```

and in my JS file I import like this:

```
import * as electron  from 'electron';
```

but I get error regarding fs.js not found in path:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/dist/fs.js
```

Can someone help on how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my issue for Aurelia Skeleton Typescript with JSPM & SystemJS: I put in index.html head which is my entry:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.node_require = require;
    delete window.require;
    delete window.exports;
    delete window.module;
  </script>
```

Then I set `nodeIntegration: true` for BrowserWindow.

And in my TS file:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    node_require: any;
  }
}

var remote: any;

if (typeof window.node_require == "function") {
  remote = window.node_require('electron').remote;
}

  closeApp() {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

depends on the loader/bundler strategy you picked

electron has nodes require() defined.
you want to redefine that before booting up your app that relies on AMD require

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/303

TL;DR
you want to assign nodes require to another variable
`window.node_require = require`
and then delete the original
`delete require`

only after this you reference a script with your app
and inside your app you use  `node_require()` to load node modules

here is the relevant comment on: [supporting electron modules in aurelia](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/217#issuecomment-237117397)

Comment: I'm using gulp with systemjs, I will try with what you suggested.

Comment: that code should be in the page that you navigate your electron renderer to outside of app

Comment: it worked. First, I put in my index.html head which is my entry:

`<script type="text/javascript">
      window.node_require = require;
      delete window.require;
      delete window.exports;
      delete window.module;
</script>`

and then I set `nodeIntegration: true` for BrowserWindow and in my TS file:

`declare global {
  interface Window {
    node_require: any;
  }
}

const remote = window.node_require('electron').remote;`

Comment: Don’t be shy. Answer your question and accept it. I tried to find you that code but failed. You got it ob your own (-;